# Assert that a collection does not contain any item in another collection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, assertions

Consider this code:

```
string[] myCollection = { "a", "b", "c", "d" }; 
string[] anotherCollection = { "c", "d" };
```

I want to test that `myCollection` does not contain any item of `anotherCollection`. How can I achieve that in NUnit?

I tried these:

```
CollectionAssert.DoesNotContain(anotherCollection, myCollection);
Assert.That(myCollection, Has.No.Member(anotherCollection));
```

...but the problem is that these functions operate on a single entity and I did not find any way to let them work with arrays.

Comment: How would you do it in regular C#? That's your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assert that a collection does *not* contain *any* of a set of items, we can check that the *intersection* of another collection is empty using LINQ:

```
string[] subject = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
string[] forbidden = { "c", "d" };

Assert.IsEmpty(subject.Intersect(forbidden)); 
// Or:
Assert.That(subject.Intersect(forbidden), Is.Empty);
```

The test shown above will fail because both collections contain the values `"c"` and `"d"`.

If we want the test to fail only when the collection contains *all* of the prohibited items:

```
Assert.That(subject.Intersect(forbidden), Is.Not.EquivalentTo(forbidden));
// Or:
Assert.That(subject, Is.Not.SupersetOf(forbidden));
```

Comment: This approach is helpful because NUnit will print which items were in both collections.

Comment: Thanks, @LeeLouviere. This particular question asks about checking that _multiple_ items in one collection do not exist in the other. The `CollectionAssert.DoesNotContain()` assertion only checks one item. We could write a loop that performs the assertion for each unwanted value, but LINQ provides a more succinct expression in this case. Be aware that `DoesNotContain()` accepts any `System.Object` sub-type for the unwanted value, so the test may falsely succeed when passing another collection.

Comment: For the people who get here because they're looking for a reversal of Assert.Contains, use CollectionAssert.DoesNotContain. This only compares one item to a list, however, and doesn't answer the question.